# Multiselect dropdown search is very slow with large data

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hi i am using multiselect dropdown, using select2 jquery 4.0.3
i am getting data using Viewbag and loading around 9000 data in viewbag below is the dropdown

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Tags, ViewBag.tags1 as IEnumerable<SelectListItem> , "----Select tags----", new { @class = "Tags form-control", multiple = "multiple", @id = "Tags" })

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#Tags").select2({
            placeholder: "Select Tags",
            minimumInputLength: 3,
            tags: true
        })
     });
</script>
```

`ViewBag.tags1` contains my data , now my page load perfectly but while searching (type required data in dropdown search box) dropdown reacts very very slow.

It feels like system has got hanged, any action in that search box is very slow.

Any solution for this?
Need help.

Comment: load only first 50 options, when user starts typing then go get it from db.

Comment: Hi thanks for your replay,i am able to return data in Array format but its not working, getting data through ajax and returning json....any example you have please share

Answer (score 0):

Loading 9000 items and inserting it to DOM is a bad idea.

Please see the code below, it will be easy to implement. This will allow you to load the data by page.

You need to create an endpoint that returns JSON.

```
$(".js-data-example-ajax").select2({
  ajax: {
    url: "https://api.github.com/search/repositories",
    dataType: 'json',
    delay: 250,
    data: function (params) {
      return {
        q: params.term, // search term
        page: params.page
      };
    },
    processResults: function (data, params) {
      // parse the results into the format expected by Select2
      // since we are using custom formatting functions we do not need to
      // alter the remote JSON data, except to indicate that infinite
      // scrolling can be used
      params.page = params.page || 1;

      return {
        results: data.items,
        pagination: {
          more: (params.page * 30) < data.total_count
        }
      };
    },
    cache: true
  },
  escapeMarkup: function (markup) { return markup; }, // let our custom formatter work
  minimumInputLength: 1,
  templateResult: formatRepo, // omitted for brevity, see the source of this page
  templateSelection: formatRepoSelection // omitted for brevity, see the source of this page
});
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your replay ,i have used ajax and returning data using json..but its not working, i am not able to populate the dropdown using the data which i am getting in items

Comment: @KalpeshKoli, create a fiddle so people can see your code or show the example in your post so we can see the problem. if you caught some errors include them so we can help you. https://jsfiddle.net/. and you example above is already populated will data from server.

Comment: I found my answer here " http://www.datahaunting.com/mvc/select2-remote-data-example-in-asp-net-mvc/ " thank you all